# Double join from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, left-join

I have (simplified) two tables, `lesson` and `charge`.

I want to show all lessons once the current charge (if there is) and since when the amount is valid and in case that there is a new amount in the future I want to see by when and the new amount.

Tables' structure looks as follows:

```
-- LESSON:
lessonId   title   description  
    1      german   german course
    2      italian  italian course
    3      english  english course

-- CHARGE: 
chargeId   lessonId   validFrom   validTo     amount
   1          1       2020/09/09  2020/10/10   55
   1          1       2020/10/11               60
   3          3       2019/01/01               75
```

Desired output:

```
lessonId   title   currentAmountSince  currentAmount  amendmentDate  amendedAmount
   1       german     2020/09/09             55        2020/10/11         60
   2       italian
   3       english    2019/01/01             75
```

What I tried so far, ended up in having the same amount on every row and having lessonId 1 duplicate:

```
SELECT l.lessonId, l.title, c.validFrom, c.amount, cF.validFrom, cF.amount FROM Lesson l
LEFT JOIN charge c on l.lessonId = c.lessonId AND c.`from` <= CURRENT_DATE AND c.`to` >= CURRENT_DATE OR c.`to` IS NULL 
LEFT JOIN charge cF on l.lessonId = cF.lessonId AND cF.`from` >= CURRENT_DATE
```

How do I get to my desired result?
Or is it more performant, to load the lesson and charge list and map the data with Java somehow?

Comment: *"Or is it more performant, ..."* --- If the `charge` table has an index on `lessonId`, then this code should perform well.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Please ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question per post. PS Re "performant": Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097) Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. [ask] [help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should be able to do this with `left join`s:

```
select l.lessonid, l.title, 
    c1.validfrom current_amount_since,
    c1.amount    curent_amount,
    c2.validfrom amendment_date,
    c2.amount    amended_amount
from lesson l
left join charge c1
    on  c1.lessonid = l.lessonid
    and c1.validfrom <= current_date
    and (c1.validto  >= current_date or c1.validto is null)
left join charge c2
    on  c2.lessonid = l.lessonid
    and c2.validfrom > current_date
```

Notes:

- the `or` conditions in the first `left join` needs to be surrounded with parentheses (otherwise, it allows *any* row with `charge` whose end date is null, regardless of its lesson id or start date)
- you probably want a strict inequality on the start date in the second join, to avoid a given charge row to match in both joins

Comment: The question *has* left joins.

Comment: @Andreas: it does, but there are issues with the join conditions. See my edit.

Comment: That's much better.

Comment: @Andreas: well, the query in the initial version of the answer already had what I think is the proper fix. I just expanded the answer with an explanation afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I think you where very close. Try this: Note the extra () in the second line.

```
SELECT l.lessonId, l.title, c.validFrom, c.amount, cF.validFrom, cF.amount FROM Lesson l
LEFT JOIN charge c on l.lessonId = c.lessonId AND c.`from` <= CURRENT_DATE AND (c.`to` >= CURRENT_DATE OR c.`to` IS NULL) 
LEFT JOIN charge cF on l.lessonId = cF.lessonId AND cF.`from` > CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked just perfectly! Thanks very much!!